Не подключается зависимость libyaraNET на vs 2022
Использую visual studio 2022, скачал проект с гита и там есть зависимость libyara.NET, она также требует того, чтобы вместе с ней была скачена еще одна зависимость Microsoft.O365.Security.Native.libyara.NET.
Пробовал удалять и скачивать заново, перезагружал vs 2022 и после удаления, и установки, но ничего не получается, подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как ее можно решить? Код пишу исключительно для винды 11, пишу службу, не использую .Net Core




Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Если у вас проект .NET (судя по метке), а вы ставите на него библиотеку .NET Framework, то естественно будет возникать. Ищите либо аналоги на .NET, либо делайте даунгрейд проекта до древнего .NET Framework.
